# Comparing None to several variables in Python3

Tags: python, types, nonetype

Is there anyone that can tell my why I get this type of return value?

```
>>> a = 7
>>> b = None
>>> bool(a and b)
False
>>> bool((a is None) and (b is None))
False
>>> bool((a and b) is None) # (a and b) eq False
True
>>> bool(False is None)
False
```

I just can't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Comment: `a and b` resolves to `a` if it's false-y, `b` otherwise. `(a and b) is None` is **not** the same as `a is None and b is None`.

Comment: Did any of the answers resolve your question? If so, would you mind accepting the one that did. Not only does this allow you to give back to the answerers for taking the time to answer your question, but it also serves to better the SO community by showing users the correct resolution for the issue you faced. This can be a great asset for other users facing the same issue. If none of the answers solved your problem, can you add details to the closest answer so that it can be adjusted to fully answer it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain

```py
>>> 7 and None
None
>>> bool(None)
False
```

So to answer:

- `a and b` gives `None` and **not** `False` as you put in comment.
- `bool(a and b)` gives `False`

So then when you replace `a and b` by its real value:

- you get `bool(None is None)` which is `True`.

I believe you had `bool(bool(a and b) is None)` in mind, which would give `False`

Answer (score 0):

Python's `and` actually returns the last value tested. For `x and y`, if `x` is false, it will return `x`; if `x` is true, it will return `y`. For example:

```
>>> 0 and ''
0
>>> 0 and 'x'
0
>>> 1 and ''
''
>>> 1 and 'x'
'x'
```

So when you do `a and b`, you get `None`.

Source: [Documentation: Boolean Operations — and, or, not](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

Comment: What do you mean by _returns the last value tested_?

Comment: @Alexander I clarified

Answer (score 0):

Consider these two facts:

1. `None` is false
2. `and` returns true if both variables are true.

In every case that misleads you, you did not consider these facts.

Comment: Just to clarify, `None` is not false, `None`'s truth value is `False`. I only correct this because it could seem unclear if taken "pythonically" (in which case `None is False` evaluates to `False`). Also, `and` returns the first operand if it has a negative truth value, otherwise, it returns the second operand. So `0 and 1` would return `0`, but `1 and 2` would return `2`.

Answer (score 0):

All Python builtins and most instances have implicit truth values thanks to their [`__bool__` magic methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__). In your case, you are working with the builtin types of `int` and `None`. In pure python, the `__bool__` method for an `int` would like something like the following:

```
class int(object):
...
    def __bool__(self):
        return self != 0 # True as long as not equal to 0
...
```

And for a `None` it would be the following:

```
class NoneType(object):
    ...
    def __bool__(self):
        return False # Always False
    ...
```

Whenever an operation is done that requires the variable to be treated as a boolean (`and`, `or`, `not`, `bool` casting), these `__bool__` magic methods are used to get their corresponding instance's truth value.

So with this in mind, let's look at your expressions one-by-one.

```
>>> bool(a and b)
False
```

`a` is the integer `7`, so by its `__bool__` magic method, it has a positive truth value (`True`). `b` is `None`, and it has a negative truth value (`False`). When you `and` variables in Python, if the first `and` operand has a positive truth value, `and` will always return the second operand (the opposite behavior can be seen with `or`). More information on this can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not). So when you do `a and b`, `None` is returned because `a` has a positive truth value. The resulting `None` is then casted to a `bool` which as shown in `None`'s `__bool__` method above, will be `False`.

```
>>> bool((a is None) and (b is None))
False
```

This evaluates to False as `a` is not `None`. Here, since you are using `is` in the statements, you are not comparing truth value, but you are checking if they are the same object. Since `7` and `None` are not the same instance, it results to `False`, causing the rest of the statement to evaluate to `False`.

```
>>> bool((a and b) is None) # (a and b) eq False (should be None)
True
```

Following up from the first one, `a and b` will return `None`. since `None` is the same instance as `None`, `None is None` evaluates to `True`. The casting to `bool` is redundant.

```
>>> bool(False is None)
False
```

Lastly, here we are once again checking if `False` and `None` are the same instance. As they are not, this evaluates to `False` and the casting to `bool` is once again redundant.